# SQL join to update one table with reference to another

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables:

Table customer:

```
ID ---- customerName ------ active
1 ------ Test ------------- true
2 ------ Bla   ------------- true
```

Now, I have another table called configuration, and I want to update this table by using the row ID (from customer).

Configuration table:

```
ID ------------- row1
1 --------------- 'test' 
2 ----------------'xyz'
```

How can I use the ID from customer table to update configuration table?

EDIT: I am using postgresql and
 I want to update row1 for every ID (that I get from customer table) to be 'blabla'.

So the output of configuration table should be:

ID ------------- row1

1 --------------- 'blabla'

2 ----------------'blabla'

Can anyone help please?

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Show the before and after data.

Comment: your sample is not clear to me you should explain the expected  result  ..  (the value for ID  = 2 repeated  two times??)

Comment: @scaisEdge I want to update row1 in configuration table by using the ID from  customer table. I have over 2000 Id's.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
update configuration set row1 = 'your value'
where id in
(select id from customer);
```

Comment: Thank you but this will update ID = 1 and ID = 2 and so on? Because I have over 2000 ID's. Don't I need to use JOIN?

Comment: Yes, it will update for each row exists in customer table

Answer (score 0):

you could use a proper join where condition

```
update configuration  c 
set c.row1 = a.your_col
FROM customer a 
where a.id = c.id
```